# How to view "recently installed extensions" in visual-studio-code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

- I installed an extension today
- that extension messed a lot of stuff up
- I can't remember the name of it,
- but it's one of about 2 extensions that I installed today.

Is there an easy way to figure out what it was other than using
[extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) (which isn't that easy for something so
simple)?

Comment: Can you go to the extensions folder and check the date there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a UNIX system, you can list extensions and sort by last update time by running something like `ls -lt ~/.vscode/extensions/*/package.json`. If you want to sort by first installation time ever, try instead `ls -lt ~/.vscode/extensions`.

The general principle is to check the creation/modification time of the extension's installation, which can be found under the `.vscode/extensions` directory under your user home directory.

Note that when you uninstall an extension through the VS Code UI, VS Code does not delete the extension's files from that `~/.vscode/extensions` directory, so the next time you reinstall it again through the VS Code UI, the directory's timestamp won't have changed.